# Tikz picture is not aligned properly in beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis}
\begin{itemize}
\item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium.\\
\item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item ed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque. 
    \item Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa.
\end{enumerate} \bigskip
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=0.8,every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
        % x node set with absolute coordinates
        \node[state] (x) at (0,0) {$1$};

    % y node set relative to x.
    % Locations can be:
    % right,left,above,below,
    % above left,below right, etc
    \node[state] (y) [right =of x] {$2$};
    \node[state] (z) [right =of y] {$3$};
    \node[state,draw=none] (d) [below =of x] {};
    \node[state,draw=none] (e) [right =of d] {};
    \node[state,draw=none] (f) [right =of e] {};
    \node[state,draw=none] (g) [above =of x] {};
    \node[state,draw=none] (h) [right =of g] {};
    \node[state,draw=none] (i) [right =of h] {};
    % Directed edge
    \path[-] (x) edge (y);
    \path[-] (z) edge (y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \qquad
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick, scale=0.3,every node/.style={scale=0.8}]
        \node[state] (x) at (0,0) {$1$};
        \node[state] (y) [right =of x] {$2$};
        \node[state] (z) [right =of y] {$3$};
        \node[state] (w) [below =of x] {$1$};
        \node[state] (q) [right =of w] {$2$};
        \node[state] (t) [right =of q] {$3$};
        \node[state] (a) [below =of w] {$1$};
        \node[state] (b) [right =of a] {$2$};
        \node[state] (c) [right =of b] {$3$};
        \path (x) edge (y);
        \path (y) edge (z);
        \path (q) edge (w);
        \path (q) edge (t);
        \path (c) edge (b);
        \path (b) edge (a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

The left side of this picture is not aligned with either of the drawings on the right. Can anyone find a way to fix this? The libraries I use are shapes,decorations,arrows,calc,arrows.meta,fit,positioning. The picture on the left was fine previously. In the picture on the right, the first diagram should have one arrow pointing from 1 to 2 and one from 2 to 3. The second diagram should have an arrow pointing from 2 to 1 and one from 2 to 3. The third diagram should have an arrow pointing from 3 to 2 and one pointing from 2 to 1.

[image]

Comment: I added a few strings to your code to get a minimal working example. If you agree with this adjustment could you please clarify your question a bit.

Comment: @kabenyuk The question title mentions beamer, so editing the example to use standalone is misleading, I don't think that was a good idea.

Comment: @TorbjørnT I agree with you and have corrected standalone to beamer. However, it seems to me that the question still needs clarification. Although, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Thank you for all your edits. It is indeed in beamer and there is some random text at the beginning of the frame, I will edit to reflect that.

Comment: @kabenyuk I uncommented the center commands because in my example they are  present. In any case, it is misaligned even without the center command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, that you looking for the following:

[image]

By use of the `chains` library, code is simple and short:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,
                chains,
                positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    suspend join/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}},
        }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Automata?}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 11mm and 11mm,
        start chain = going right,
state/.append style = {minimum size=8mm, inner sep=0pt,
                       on chain, join=by -},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes=state]
\node       {$1$};
\node       {$2$};
\node (x)   {$3$};
\node[suspend join,
      right=of x]   (y) {$1$};
\node       {$2$};
\node       {$3$};
\node[suspend join,
      above=of y]       {$1$};
\node       {$2$};
\node       {$3$};
\node[suspend join,
      below=of y]       {$1$};
\node       {$2$};
\node       {$3$};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Your question is not clear. You should add information about content of frame with desired image and also provide an sketch, which show connections between nodes.

Possible skeleton, that you can finish image in form which you are after:

**Edit:**
After last edit of your question it seems that image should be as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                chains,
                positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    suspend join/.code = {\def\tikz@after@path{}},
        }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Automata?}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 7mm and 11mm,
        start chain = A going right,
                  > = {Straight Barb[line width=0.5pt,%
                                     angle=90:4pt 4]},
state/.append style = {semithick, minimum size=6mm, 
                       inner sep=0pt, font=\small, 
                       on chain},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state, join=by ->}]
\node   {$1$};  % A-1
\node   {$2$};
\node   {$3$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[nodes=state]
\node[suspend join,
      right=of A-3] {$1$};
\node   {$2$};
\node   {$3$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state, join=by ->}]
\node[suspend join,
      above=of A-4] {$1$};
\node   {$2$};
\node   {$3$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state, join=by <-}]
\node[suspend join,
      below=of A-4] {$1$};
\node   {$2$};
\node   {$3$};  % A-12
    \end{scope}
\draw[->]   (A-5) edge (A-4)
                  edge (A-6)
            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your nice reply. Only the arrows on the left picture should have no head. Those in the right picture should have heads (point in a direction that I can choose).

Comment: Also, the picture is too big because there's other text in the frame. Can I scale it down to 60 or 70%? Sorry but I never used this library

Comment: @Karl, scaling I will left to you. You can for example educe `node distance` and `minimum size` accordingly. Also you can use smaller font size. You not gives any information about desired size of image or size of other elements of frame.

Comment: Sure, scaling I will manage. But how do I get arrow heads on some diagrams? I mean right now they are all segments, whereas some need to be segments, others need to be "normal" arrows.

Comment: having arrows in diagram was not par of question. Please edit it and show what you like that image be. Arrows can be done by `join=by ->`

Comment: Ok, I just edited as you instructed.

Comment: @Karl, see addendum and its edit.

Comment: Manage, thank you.